# How to shorten URL with Bitly V4 API using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, api, url-shortener

I currently use the below PowerShell script to shorten any URL via the Bitly V3 API.  I am hoping someone can help to do the same thing using the Bitly V4 API.

```PowerShell
function New-ShortURL {
    param (
            [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
            $URL
        )
    #https://app.bitly.com API
    $OAuthToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    $MyURL=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten -Body @{access_token=$OAuthToken;longURL=$URL} -Method Get
    $MyURLjson = $MyURL.Content | convertfrom-json
    $MyURLjson.data.url
}
```

Comment: have you read [the documentation](https://dev.bitly.com/v4/#section/Authentication) on how to migrate from v3 to v4?

Comment: Yes I did.  I wasn't able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through the [documentation on changes to v4](https://dev.bitly.com/v4/#section/Authentication), it states,

*Previous versions of the API used a query parameter to submit the token. This is no longer applicable in v4.0. Tokens should be made using the OAuth Bearer Token specification, using the Authorization header in the request.*

What that means is, you cant do this,

```
$body = @{access_token=$OAuthToken;longURL=$URL}
```

instead, you have to put the access token in the header of your request.

```
$header = @{Authorization = "Bearer $OAuthToken"
```

And [the method](https://dev.bitly.com/v4/#operation/createBitlink) ... seems to be POST instead of GET.

Your request should look something like this,

```
$body = @{long_url= "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60418169/how-to-shorten-url-with-bitly-v4-api-using-powershell?noredirect=1#comment106889121_60418169"} | convertto-json

$OAuthToken = "=========="
$header = @{Authorization="Bearer $OAuthToken"; Accept="application/json"; "Content-Type"="application/json"}

$MyURL=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten -Body $body -header $header -Method Post
$MyURLjson = $MyURL.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$MyURLjson.link
```

Comment: I just tried that script using my API token from V3.  However, it doesnt return a shortened link.  It says "forbidden".  I need to know how to generate the OAuth2 token for this script.

Comment: Use the link to documentation I gave to see how to get the auth token. You use the same call but use -credential switch to retrieve auth token

Comment: Thank you.  I was able to generate a generic API token which worked with your script.  I was worried I "HAD" to use an API client key + client secret just to generate the OAuth2 token each time.

Comment: Client key and secret are listed as optional.